# Infinite loop with @keyframes

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I have a problem with animating icons vertically so that they change each other infinitely.

The problem is that I have two icons and I need them to change in the way (1st icon - frog, 2nd icon - bird) 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 so that in looks like a full loop going in one direction(bottom), what I have now is that 1st icon to 2nd changes as wanted and then my animation goes back to first icon going backwards instead of forward.

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/sedulka/pen/QWpLJBm)

I will be very glad if someone could help me.

```
@keyframes rotate {
 10%, 15% {
        transform: translateY(0);
 }
 25%,36% {
        transform: translateY(-45px);
 }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for something like slideshow effect, when image freezes there for some time. This example is close (codepen.io/gradar/pen/BaavLLo), I need something like that but looped

Comment: Just duplicate the first icon and place it in the last position it will give a loop effect.I did the same

Answer (score 5):

### This will work for u

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400');
body {
  background: #643a7a;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel .change_inner {
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  animation: rotate 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0%,
  15% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  50%,
  66% {
    transform: translateY(-45px);
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-90px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU' crossorigin='anonymous'>

<div class="carousel">
  <div class="change_inner">
    <div class="element"><i class='fas fa-frog'></i></div>
    <div class="element"><i class='fas fa-dove'></i></div>
    <div class="element"><i class='fas fa-frog'></i></div>
  </div>

</div>
```